# Low volume in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio

I am experiencing really low volume in Google Chrome and I cannot understand why!

I have checked the version of Flash that Google is using, I have checked all the volume levels in Windows and everything is correct!

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is volume normal outside of Chrome?  Does the embedded player have a volume control?

Comment: Yes, and the volume control on the player is maxed. This is across several websites, including; bbc.co.uk/news, YouTube

Answer (score 0):

If everything Steven asked is answered "yes", then try reinstalling chrome. You have a weird issue that, if not caused by volume controls being low in the embedded player or in windows mixer, might be easily fixed by a reinstall of the application.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this last week. The audio seems to be low in all browsers, which is a little strange.

Comment: What about in other applicantions that aren't browser based? Such as windows media player, windows OS itself, etc?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after lots of searching and testing this seems to have fixed the issue.

[Solution](http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/288802-realtek-hd-low-volume-fix.html)

1. Open Realtek HD Audio Manager from taskbar
2. Under ANALOG you should have inputs, right click the green input (Depends if you have it plugged on front or back) and choose Connector Retasking
3. Check the option "Headphone"

Now the volume should be louder.

Comment: PLease provide an excerpt of the solution. If the link eventually gets broken, future readers would at least have this excerpt.